# When $\frac{d}{dt} E[ e^{-|X-t|} ]= E \left[ \frac{d^m}{dt^m}e^{-|X-t|} \right]$ for all $m \ge 1$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with absolutely continuous pdf.

I am interested in finding conditions on $X$ such that
\begin{align}
\frac{d^m}{dt^m} E[ e^{-|X-t|} ]= E \left[  \frac{d^m}{dt^m}e^{-|X-t|} \right]
\end{align}
for a.e. $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and all $m \ge 1$.

The issue I am having that $\frac{d^m}{dt^m}e^{-|X-t|}$ is not differentiable if $X=t$.

I would really appreciate a details answer that would take care of all technical aspects such why or why not  Leibnitz rule can be used here?

Comment: @Jason yes. Thank you. Corrected.

Comment: The equation in your title is different from the equation in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $t_0\in\mathbb R$. Since $X$ has a pdf, $X\neq t$ almost surely, and so $e^{-|X-t|}$ is almost surely differentiable at $t=t_0$. Moreover, the derivative is bounded in absolute value by $1$. You can  apply the bounded convergence theorem to deduce the result for $m=1$. The general case follows by induction using an identical argument.

Comment: Jason. Can you please put more detail on the induction method? Also, how do you show that all derivative are absolutely bounded by $1$.

Comment: Once you know the $m$ case, apply my reasoning again to obtain the $m+1$ case. Observe that $\frac{\partial^m}{\partial t^m}e^{-|X-t|}=\operatorname{sign}(X-t)^me^{-|X-t|}$, so there is no extra difficulty in the induction step as opposed to the base case. Can you see why these functions are bounded by $1$?

Comment: Sure, I see that it is bounded by $1$.  My issue is that this bound holds a.e. only and not everywhere, right?  At $X=t$ the high order derivative do not exist, right? Is this a problem?

Comment: Whenever you are dealing with an integral/expectation, you can ignore events which occur with measure zero. So no, it is no problem. If it makes you more comfortable, write $E[e^{-|X-t|}]=E[e^{-|X-t|}\mathbf1_{\{X\neq t\}}]$ and apply.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. So, the conclusion is that the function $f(t)=E[ e^{-|X-t|}$ is infinitely differentiable for all $t$, correct?  The emphasis on all $t$ is correct I think, right?

Comment: Yes. An important thing to remember for these kind of questions is differentiability is a local property. So fix a specific (but arbitrary) $t$, and prove differentiability there. Hence it is differentiable for all $t$, so when we look at the second derivative, there is no issue with the function being differentiable at some points and not others, so we prove the second derivative exists at a specific point, and hence for all points, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. Another question. We have shown that $f(t)$ is differentiable everywhere.  I have a question now.  Let $g(t)$ be a function that is analytic on every neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}$ except one point (this is like $e^{-|x|}$ ).  Is it true that $E[ g(X-t)]$ is an analytic function on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I can ask this question separately, of course.

Comment: That's an interesting question which I do not have an immediate answer to. Asking another question is a good idea!

Comment: Great. I will post this soon.  I have one more final question. Suppose, $X$ is a distribution that has an atom.   Then the result still holds but almost every only, right?   Using your argument fix $t_0$ then $E[e^{-|X-t|}]=E[e^{-|X-t_0|} \cdot 1_{X \neq t_0}]+ E[e^{-|X-t_0|} \cdot 1_{X = t_0}]=E[e^{-|X-t_0|} \cdot 1_{X \neq t_0}]+P[X=t_0]$.  But since $P[X=t_0]=0$ is a.e. the result hold almost everywhere, right?  And the result of a general $m$ would also hold but with addtion that result holds only for a.e. $t$, right?

Comment: Yes, this seems right. In general, you should have infinite differentiability at any $t$ which is not in the closure of the set of atoms of $X$.

Comment: Ok. I posted a new question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372503/let-gx-be-analytic-on-every-interval-that-does-not-contain-0-is-ft-eg