# Let $g(x)$ be analytic on every interval that does not contain $0$ is $f(t)= E[g(X-t)]$ analytic

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, analyticity

Let $g(x)$ be a continuous function that is analytic on every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ that does not contain $0$.

An example of such a function is: $e^{-|x|}$.

Let $X$ be a random variable and define
\begin{align}
f(t)= E[g(X-t)]
\end{align}
That is we are looking at the convolution integral and suppose that $|g(t)|<c<\infty$ for all $t$.

We want to look at analytic properties of $f(t)$ without many assumptions on $X$.

**I have two question about this:**

1. Does $f(t)$ have the same property as $g(t)$? That is $f(t)$ is analytic on every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ except one point.
2. If in addition, we assume that $X$ has an absolutely continuous distribution. Is $f(t)$ analytic everwhere?

This question was inspired by a similar question raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371779/when-fracddt-e-e-x-t-e-left-fracdmdtme-x-t-right/2372371?noredirect=1#comment4889692_2372371).

**My attempts**

I was only more or less able to answer 1).

To study this we can fix $t$ and look at
\begin{align}
f(t)=E[g(X-t)]&=E[g(X-t) 1_{X \neq t}]+ E[g(X-t) 1_{X = t}]\\
&= E[g(X-t) 1_{X \neq t}]+  g(0)P[ X = t]. \quad (*)
\end{align}

We see from (*) that $f(t)$ is a.e. differentiable.  Moreover, if we assume that $X$ has no atoms then $f(t)$ is differentiable everywhere since $P[X=t]=0$.

Let $T=\{t:P[X=t]>0 \}$. Equation(*)  seems to be suggesting that 1) is false if $|T|\ge 2$ and $f(t)$ will not be differentiable for $t$ such that $P[X=t]>0$.

Moreover, ,  $T=\{t:P[X=t]>0 \}$  can be a dense set so it appears that $f(t)$ may not be analytic on any neightborhood of $\mathbb{R}$.

Unless I am wrong, this appears to be very intersting since I alway thought that convolution makes things "more" smooth. However, in this case, things get "less" smooth.

I would really appreciate if some one can clarify these for me.

For 2). It seems that $f(t)$ is infinitely differentiable for all $t$, since $P[X=t]=0$ for all $t$. So, it seem resonable to ask if $f(t)$ is analytic everywhere?

Comment: Note that, with no further assumptions on $X$, $P[X=t]$ need not be differentiable anywhere. For example, let $X=\frac{Y_1-Y_2}{Y_3}$ where $(Y_i)$ are iid from a geometric distribution. Then $P[X=t]>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb Q$, but $P[X=t]=0$ for $t\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, so the function is not even continuous anywhere. Your answer to 1) is correct provided the *closure* of the set of atoms of $X$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @Jason Quick question if $P[X=t]=0$ for  $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then $P[X=t]=0$ almost everywhere. So the function is almost everywhere contininous, right?

Comment: No. It *is* continuous (contrary to what I said earlier), but not because of what you said. E.g. the function $\mathbf1_{\mathbb Q}$ is zero almost everywhere but continuous nowhere. However, this particular function is continuous on $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ since for any $\varepsilon>0$, $P [X=t]\ge\varepsilon$ for at most finitely many $t$. Differentiability will be more subtle, I'm not sure right now.

Comment: I am still unable to resolve whether in fact $P[X=t]$ is differentiable almost everywhere; I have asked a separate question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378122/if-mu-is-a-probability-measure-on-mathbb-r-is-t-mapsto-mu-t-differen?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Jason Thanks a lot.  You get a like from me.

Comment: "Suppose that $|f(t)|<\infty$" How doe you take the absolute value of something that may not be defined? Don't you want to say $g(x-t) \in L^1(\mu)$ for all $x?$

Comment: @zhw yes, you are right. I will update.