# If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R$, is $t\mapsto\mu\{t\}$ differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372503/let-gx-be-analytic-on-every-interval-that-does-not-contain-0-is-ft-eg), the OP at one point says that since $t\mapsto P[X=t]$ is zero almost everywhere, it is almost everywhere differentiable. I pointed out that this need not be the case - $\mathbf1_{\mathbb Q}$ is the usual example of a function which is zero almost everywhere but continuous nowhere - but I realized the situation is a little more subtle in this case.

If $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb R$, then for every $\varepsilon>0$, $\mu\{t\}\ge\varepsilon$ for at most finitely many $t$. In particular, $\lim_{s\to t}\mu\{s\}=0$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$, so $t\mapsto\mu\{t\}$ is continuous at every point of continuity of $\mu$. (Recall that *point of continuity* refers to the function $t\mapsto\mu((-\infty,t])$, so this statement isn't as meaningless as it appears.) Since there can be at most countably many atoms, this shows that at the very least we *do* have a.e. continuity.

What about differentiability? This is a messier question. Obviously the function is not differentiable at any atom. If the derivative exists at $t_0$, then it must equal zero. We therefore have that differentiability at $t_0$ is equivalent to

$$\mu\{t_0+h\}=o(h)\qquad\text{as }h\to0.\qquad\qquad(\dagger)$$

Does $(\dagger)$ occur for almost every $t_0$? I don't know. I also don't know how one would prove it if they did know, either.  I had an idea for a proof of the affirmative statement, trying to prove that the set of $t$ where $\mu\{t\}=0$ but $(\dagger)$ fails is at most countable, but it didn't pan out. A counterexample would surely be messy and hard to visualize - it would need to have a countable set of atoms whose closure had nonempty interior at a minimum.

If the answer turns out to be negative, how badly behaved can the function be? Can the set $\{t:s\mapsto\mu\{s\}\text{ is differentiable at }t\}$ have zero measure?

Comment: Could you explain to me why $P[X=t]$ is a.e. continuous.   For example, if $X$ is supported on $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the set of  $P$ discontinuities is dense, right? So, it is an everywhere discontinuous function, right?

Comment: Just because the set of discontinuities is dense, does not mean the function is discontinuous everywhere. I explain in the second paragraph how to deduce that the function is a.e. continuous.

Comment: Yes, you trying to use that for every $\epsilon>0$, $\mu(t)> \epsilon$ for finitely many $t$.  This implies that, for every $\epsilon>0$, $mu(t) \le \epsilon$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus T_\epsilon$ where $T_\epsilon$ is a finite set.   However,  is there an issue with taking $\epsilon \to 0$ and $T_\epsilon$ becoming dense? I am not very clear about this.

Comment: I am just using the definition of a limit. If $T_\epsilon$ is finite, then in particular for every $t$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|s-t |<\delta$ implies $s\notin T_\epsilon$. Apply this at every fixed $t$ to deduce $\lim_{s\to t}\mu\{s\}=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I actually worked this out an hour ago. I have one more question about the answer.   I wanted to see if I understand it correctly.  The question is about probability measure with no atoms. Suppose, our probability measure contains no atoms.  Then $P[X=t]=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.  But this means that the function is $f(t)=P[X=t]$ is differentiable, right? A function that is zero everywhere is differential everywhere?

Comment: Yes, the zero function is smooth, analytic, anything you like.

Comment: So if $X$ has a Cantor distribution (which I think is atomless) then $P[X=t]$ is everywhere differentiable, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(t) = \mu \{ t \}$.

Suppose $\mu \{ x \} = 0$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$ (by which we mean $f'(x)$ might not exist). Then there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that arbitrarily close to $x$ there exists $y$ with $\mu \{ y \} \geqslant \varepsilon |y-x|$.

There is at most countably many $y$ with $\mu \{ y \} > 0$ - if there is finitely many, of course $f$ is a.e. differentiable, otherwise arrange all such $y$ into a sequence $y_m$. Then $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu \{ y_m \} = \mu( \{ y_m : m \geqslant 1 \} ) \leqslant 1.$$

Now, for $\varepsilon > 0$ let $I_m^{\varepsilon} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mu \{ y_m \} \geqslant \varepsilon |y_m-x| \}$ so $I_m^{\varepsilon}$ is an interval of radius $\frac{\mu \{ y_m \}}{\varepsilon}$ centered at $y_m$. By the remark in the beginning

$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mu \{ x \} = 0 \ \& \ f'(x) \neq 0 \} \subseteq \bigcup_{\varepsilon > 0} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} I_m^{\varepsilon}.$$

Now, for a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n \geqslant 1$ we have

$$\lambda \left( \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} I_m^{\varepsilon} \right) \leqslant \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \lambda( I_m^{\varepsilon} ) = \frac{2}{\varepsilon} \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} \mu \{ y_m \}.$$

As the series $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu \{ y_m \}$ converges, the above tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Therefore

$$\lambda \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} I_m^{\varepsilon} \right) = 0$$

and since the union over $\varepsilon > 0$ can be made countable by taking it over a sequence $\varepsilon_k = \frac{1}{k}$, we obtain

$$\lambda \big( \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mu \{ x \} = 0 \ \& \ f'(x) \neq 0 \} \big) = 0.$$

Finally, if $\mu \{ x \} \neq 0$, then $x = y_m$ for some $m$, so

$$\lambda \big( \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \mu \{ x \} \neq 0 \} \big) = 0.$$

Therefore

$$\lambda \big( \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : f'(x) \neq 0 \} \big) = 0,$$

i.e. $f'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

### Example

Recall the construction of the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set):

$$\mathcal{C} = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$$

where each $C_n$ consists of $2^n$ intervals of total length $\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^n$. Arrange them all in a sequence $I_m$ and let $y_m$ be the middle of $I_m$. Note that $y_m$ are pairwise distinct.

Now define a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ to be $\frac{1}{2}|I_m|$ on $y_m$ and $0$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ y_m : m \geqslant 1 \}$. Note that $\mu$ is a probability measure and each $I_m$ is exactly $I_m^1$ from the proof above. Since each $a \in \mathcal{C}$ belongs to intervals $I_m^1$ of arbitrarily small length, $f$ is not differentiable in any point $a \in \mathcal{C}$.

The construction can be slightly modified to replace the Cantor set with a dense $G_{\delta}$ set.

### Summary

For arbitrary probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the set of points where $t \mapsto \mu \{ t \}$ is not differentiable:

- must have measure zero;
- may contain the Cantor set;
- may contain a dense $G_{\delta}$ set.

Also, as the OP has noted, wherever the derivative exists, it must be zero.

Comment: The proof looks good, but the counterexample confuses me. What is $A^1_m$?

Comment: @Jason Um, I meant $I_m^1$ which is $I_m^{\varepsilon}$ for $\varepsilon = 1$. Sorry.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Remark: a simple modification of the example allows us to replace $\mathcal{C}$ with a dense $G_{\delta}$ set. So the set of $x$ s.t. $f'(x) = 0$ must have measure zero, but can be huge topologically.

Comment: So, can you summarize the result in one one sentence?  Is $f(t)=\mu({t})$ differentiable or not?

Comment: @Boby Good idea. I added a summary to the answer.